# How to draw & edit polygons with react-native-maps?

Tags: react-native, polygon, react-native-maps

First of all, is this doable? I haven't seen any examples anywhere at all. Can someone help me with this one?

And their [docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/polygon.md) dont seem to include any draw/edit functions.

```
<MapView
   provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE} // remove if not using Google Maps
   style={style.fullMap}
   region={{
      latitude: coordinates[0]['latitude'],
      longitude: coordinates[0]['longitude'],
      latitudeDelta: 0.002,
      longitudeDelta: 0.002,
   }}
>
   <Polygon                 
      coordinates={coordinates}
      strokeColor={allColors.green}
      fillColor={allColors.oliveLightGreen}                 
      strokeWidth={1}
      tappable={true}
      onPress={() => Alert.alert('TEST')}
   />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <MapView style={style.fullMap} 
            region={startingRegion}
            >
                <Polygon coordinates={
                    [{latitude:34.6747710,longitude:-82.8442053},
                     {latitude:34.6751705,longitude:-82.8438771},
                     {latitude:34.6745605,longitude:-82.8413771},
                     {latitude:34.6732286,longitude:-82.8423133},
                     {latitude:34.6740186,longitude:-82.8434133}
                    ]}
                    fillColor="#27f"
                    strokeColor="#27f"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    tappable={true}
                    onPress={()=> console.log("Pressed")} />
</MapView>
```

I'm not really sure what you are asking, but this is a quick one I wrote that works for me. Without knowing the rest of your code, nothing appears to me to be invalid. Mine doesn't use an Alert but in my experience using an Alert within another element is hit-or-miss if it works as you want it to.

If Alert isn't showing up and your goal is to make the Alert to show up then I would consider using a useState variable and having the onPress update the value of the variable and your alert being shown depending on the value of that variable.